# Where to find CCITT Group 4 Compression Specification?

Tags: compression, fax

I'm looking for enough of a description of the CCITT Group 4 Compression algorithm that I could write functioning code from it.  Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the specification here: http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.6-198811-I/en